# How to store the output in a textfile automatically in C programming?

Tags: c

Hei. 
I am making a document that should be able to print out to add signature. I have the document in my output in the C program, but when saved i only get the code, not the final output. 
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

   FILE*pfile=NULL;

   pfile=fopen("MY_FILE","r");

   printf("Digital Forensics Investigation Documentation Evidence Form\n\n");
   printf("Section 1: Evidence Item Record\n");

   printf("---------------------------------\n");

char array1[20][100]={"\nLab reference Number:","\nCase reference Number:","\nItem reference Number:","\nDevice Description:","\nAdditional Information:","\nSection 2: Investigator Details\n\nDevice accepted by:","\nDate and time received:","-------------------------------------------------------------------------","\n\nSignaure:\n","\n\n------------------"};

char array2[20][500]={"TDI-DF","DFI-C001-2014-10-108","EI-201","Western Digital external hard drive,1TB","\nBlack case,with a few scratches on the side and chipped corner.\nNo obvious serial number or other distinguising features.\nPower cable and USB cable still attached.\nReceived from CTO organisation.\nIt was attached to a laptop running windows 8.\nThis laptop was powered of at the time this harddrive was removed.\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------","Sara Hansen","30th December 2014 at 15:00"};
int i;

for (i=0;i<20;i++)

{

 printf("%s  %s \n", array1[i], array2[i]);

}

fscanf(pfile,"d% d% d%");

fclose(pfile);

    return 0;
}
```

I want my output to be saved in the text document asell, instead of only the code.

Can anyone please help me to find out what is missing in my code to get this saved in a text file in a proper format ?

Thank you!

Comment: Please take care when tagging - C and C# are entirely different languages.

Comment: Please Tag the question as "C" not "C#". C# is a not a C language

Comment: Clearly you are missing *everything* related to "writing a file". Are you totally in the dark about that?

Comment: What is `"d% d% d%"` in your `fscanf()`?

Comment: fopen, fscanf need to have the returned value checked to assure the operation was successful and if not successful the error needs to be handled

Comment: this line: 'fscanf(pfile,"d% d% d%");' should look more like: 'fscanf(pfile,"%d %d %d", &firstInt, &secondInt, &thirdInt);' plus have the returned value checked to assure all three operations were successful.  the code also needs to define those three int variables.

Comment: array2 only has 7 entries defined, so the line: 'printf("%s %s \n", array1[i], array2[i]);' will result in mis-aligned output text.  Suggest correcting definition of array2 to match layout of array1

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `w` mode with `fopen` to be able to write:

```
pfile = fopen("MY_FILE", "w");
```

Then use `fprintf` instead of `printf`, for example:

```
fprintf(pfile, "Digital Forensics Investigation Documentation Evidence Form\n\n");
```

Not sure what the `fscanf` line you have is trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The scanf thing was just something i tried out, was no supposed to be there. but it does not work anyway. :P With the fprintf the whole program stops working. But why do i get the code in text file? I just want the information i have written in the code. As i get in my output.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin there is no code to write to a any file in the OPs code.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @user3629249 There would be if printf was changed to fprintf.

Comment: You should use `fopen("MY_FILE", "w");` not `fopen("MY_FILE", "r");`. `r` is for reading and `w` is for writing...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It says that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, and the solution is to wrap `printf` calls in a function that prints to both, the file and `stdout` so here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void vputtext(FILE *file, const char *const format, va_list ap)
{
    vfprintf(stdout, format, ap);
    vfprintf(file, format, ap);
}

void puttext(FILE *file, const char *const format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_list copy;

    va_start(ap, format);
    va_copy(copy, ap);
    vputtext(file, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *pfile;

    pfile = fopen("MY_FILE", "w");
    if (pfile == NULL)
        return -1;

    puttext(pfile, "Digital Forensics Investigation Documentation Evidence Form\n\n");
    puttext(pfile, "Section 1: Evidence Item Record\n");

    puttext(pfile, "---------------------------------\n");

    const char *array1[10] = {
        "\nLab reference Number:",
        "\nCase reference Number:",
        "\nItem reference Number:",
        "\nDevice Description:",
        "\nAdditional Information:",
        "\nSection 2: Investigator Details\n\nDevice accepted by:",
        "\nDate and time received:",
        "-------------------------------------------------------------------------",
        "\n\nSignaure:\n","\n\n------------------"
    };

    const char *array2[10] = {
        "TDI-DF",
        "DFI-C001-2014-10-108",
        "EI-201",
        "Western Digital external hard drive,1TB",
        "\nBlack case,with a few scratches on the side and chipped corner.\nNo obvious serial number or other distinguising features.\nPower cable and USB cable still attached.\nReceived from CTO organisation.\nIt was attached to a laptop running windows 8.\nThis laptop was powered of at the time this harddrive was removed.\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------",
        "Sara Hansen",
        "30th December 2014 at 15:00",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    };

    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        puttext(pfile, "%s %s\n", array1[i], array2[i]);
    fclose(pfile);

    return 0;
}
```

You had another important error, your for loop looped until `i > 19` and you didn't initialize all the 20 strings in your array, trying ti pass those values to `printf` is undefined behavior.

You also open the file for reading `"r"` and then try to write to it, use `"w"` for overwriting the file and `"a"` for appending to it.

Now follows a suggestion of a way to do what you are trying to do which is less error prone, ther is no risk of the `array`s being of diferent sizes with this approach, and also you can add any reasonable number of elements to the array before the last `{NULL, NULL} <- sentinel` without modifying the code at all

**Here it is**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void vputtext(FILE *file, const char *const format, va_list ap)
{
    vfprintf(stdout, format, ap);
    vfprintf(file, format, ap);
}

void puttext(FILE *file, const char *const format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_list copy;

    va_start(ap, format);
    va_copy(copy, ap);
    vputtext(file, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

struct KeyValue
{
    const char *key;
    const char *value;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *pfile;
    int   i;

    pfile = fopen("MY_FILE", "w");
    if (pfile == NULL)
        return -1;

    puttext(pfile, "Digital Forensics Investigation Documentation Evidence Form\n\n");
    puttext(pfile, "Section 1: Evidence Item Record\n");

    puttext(pfile, "---------------------------------\n");

    const struct KeyValue entries[] = {
        {"\nLab reference Number:", "TDI-DF"},      
        {"\nCase reference Number:", "DFI-C001-2014-10-108"},
        {"\nItem reference Number:", "EI-201"},
        {"\nDevice Description:", "Western Digital external hard drive,1TB"},
        {"\nAdditional Information:", "\nBlack case,with a few scratches on the side and chipped corner.\nNo obvious serial number or other distinguising features.\nPower cable and USB cable still attached.\nReceived from CTO organisation.\nIt was attached to a laptop running windows 8.\nThis laptop was powered of at the time this harddrive was removed.\n\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------"},
        {"\nSection 2: Investigator Details\n\nDevice accepted by:", "Sara Hansen"},
        {"\nDate and time received:", "30th December 2014 at 15:00"},
        {"-------------------------------------------------------------------------", ""},
        {"\n\nSignaure:\n", ""},
        {"\n\n------------------", ""},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };

    for (i = 0 ; entries[i].key != NULL ; ++i)
        puttext(pfile, "%s %s\n", entries[i].key, entries[i].value);
    fclose(pfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. After some small changes it works as i wanted it to! I changed from printf to fprintf, and i added pfile at the end... fprintf(pfile, "%s %s \n"); 
I now have it in a document. 
Thank you very much!:)